# Install DirectX & VCRedist in freearc default script when progress bar is full & paused after main file extraction

Tags: inno-setup

I want to make a iss script by editing 'Inno Setup Free Arc' default script (script link descripted below)

[Script Link Here.](http://freearc.org/download/InnoSetup/ISFreeArcExtract%20v.4.0.rar)

Setup will contain:-

1. Redist directory (contain DXWebSetup.exe,VCRedist.exe)
2. Setup.exe
3. data1.bin (data1.arc file name changed to data1.bin)
4. data2.bin (data2.arc file name changed to data2.bin)

I want to make the script like this:-

1. Setup will start by user > Buton 'Next'.
2. Browse directory option (user may browse) > Buton 'Next'.
3. DirectX & VCRedist checkbox (user will select) > Buton 'Next'.
4. Confirmation before install > Buton 'Install'.
5. Installing (extracting freearc archive) > Progress Bar is progressing.
6. When progress bar will full (after extracting freearc archive) it (progress bar) will paused & DirectX or VCRedist or both will be started one by one as user select.
7. Installation finish > Buton 'Finish'.

How can i edit this script?

PLEASE TELL ME THE EDITED PART OF THIS SCRIPT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What u asked in your question most part will be done by default freearc script.

If u want 'vcredist' and 'directX' checkbox in components/task page u can simply add the entry
to script.

**If u want 'vcredist' and 'directX' checkbox in Components  page u can add those entry like this:**

```
[Components]
Name: Directx; Description: Install DirectX; Types: custom
Name: Visualc; Description: Install Visual C++; Types: custom
```

*If u don't want to show the `combobox` in components page then add this :*

```
[Types]
Name: custom; Description: custom; Flags: iscustom
```

**NOTE:** Look at the `Types: custom` in `[Components]`,if u want to show the combox then remove `iscustom` flag from `[Types]` section.

**If u want 'vcredist' and 'directX' checkbox in Task  page u can add those entry like this:**

```
[Tasks]
Name: Directx; Description: Install DirectX; Flags: unchecked
Name: Visualc; Description: Install Visual C++; Flags: unchecked
```

**Now To link those Components/Tasks to `[Run]` u have to add those to `[Run]` section like this:**

*If u choose Components page then :*

```
[Run]
Filename: {src}\Redist\VCRedist.exe; StatusMsg: Installing Visual C++...; Components: Visualc
Filename: {src}\Redist\DXWebSetup.exe; StatusMsg: Installing DirectX...; Components: Directx
```

*If u choose Tasks page then :*

```
[Run]
Filename: {src}\Redist\VCRedist.exe; StatusMsg: Installing Visual C++...; Tasks: Visualc
Filename: {src}\Redist\DXWebSetup.exe; StatusMsg: Installing DirectX...; Tasks: Directx
```

Now just put 'VCRedist.exe' and 'DXWebSetup.exe' inside "Redist" folder in your output directory({src} means output directory).

Other parts_(Next Button,browse,install etc)_ of your question will be done automatically by default freearc script.