# Inno Setup - How to force programs started from Inno Setup to open on a certain place on the screen?

Tags: inno-setup

With this code: [Install DirectX & VCRedist in freearc default script when progress bar is full & paused after main file extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238243/install-directx-vcredist-in-freearc-default-script-when-progress-bar-is-full) I can install DirectX and VCRedist with Inno Setup. But, is it possible to force the installation window of these programs to a certain place on the screen? For example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hardly possible to make an application to start at desired position, unless the application explicitly supports it.

So in general, what you can do is to watch for a certain window to appear and move it afterwards. You can identify the window by its caption ([`FindWindowByWindowName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_findwindowbywindowname)) or class ([`FindWindowByClassName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_findwindowbyclassname)). Drawback is that the window will briefly appear on its default position.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "DXWebSetup.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\DXWebSetup.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing DirectX..."; \
  BeforeInstall: StartWaitingForDirectXWindow; \
  AfterInstall: StopWaitingForDirectXWindow


[Code]

function SetTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent, uElapse, lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@User32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'KillTimer@User32.dll stdcall';
function GetTickCount: DWord; external 'GetTickCount@kernel32 stdcall';
function SetWindowPos(hWnd: HWND; hWndInsertAfter: HWND; X: Integer; Y: Integer;
  cx: Integer; cy: Integer; uFlags: UINT): BOOL;
  external 'SetWindowPos@user32.dll stdcall'; 

const
  SWP_NOSIZE = $01;  
  SWP_NOZORDER = $04;

var
  WindowWaitTimer: LongWord;
  WindowWaitStarted: DWord;
  MoveWindowRunning: Boolean;

procedure MoveDirectXWindowProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  Retry: Boolean;
  Handle: HWND;
begin
  Handle := FindWindowByWindowName('Installing Microsoft(R) DirectX(R)');
  if Handle = 0 then
  begin
    if DWord(GetTickCount - WindowWaitStarted) < 5000 then
    begin
      Log('DirectX window not found, will try again shortly');
      Retry := True;
    end
     else
    begin
      Log('Giving up waiting for DirectX window');
      Retry := False;
    end
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('DirectX window found');

    SetWindowPos(
      Handle, 0, WizardForm.Left + ScaleX(150), WizardForm.Top + ScaleX(30),
      0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
    Retry := False;
  end;

  if not Retry then
  begin
    Log('Stopping timer');
    KillTimer(0, WindowWaitTimer);
    WindowWaitTimer := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure StartWaitingForDirectXWindow;
begin
  Log('Starting waiting for DirectX window');
  WindowWaitTimer := SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@MoveDirectXWindowProc));
  WindowWaitStarted := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure StopWaitingForDirectXWindow;
begin
  if WindowWaitTimer <> 0 then
  begin
    Log('DirectX installer finished, and we are still waiting for its window, stopping');
    KillTimer(0, WindowWaitTimer);
    WindowWaitTimer := 0;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('DirectX installer finished, and we are no longer waiting for its window');
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

---

[image: Windows positions]